# A good way to iterate through a 2D tic-tac-toe array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, validation, 2d, tic-tac-toe

I have a function for checking if an array has three of the same character for a tic-tac-toe array. Trouble is, I'm having an issue with the logic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
        if (board[i][j] != '*'){
            if (i != j){
                if (board[i][i] == board[i][j]){
                    matches++;
                }
                else if (board[i][j] == board[j][i]){
                    matches++;
                }
                else if (board[i][j] == board[j][j]){
                    matches++;
                }
                else if (board[i][j] == board[j][i]){
                    matches++;
                }
                else {
                    matches = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that I can check for horizontally and vertically for matchings. But, I can't quite figure out how to find the diagonal matchings. I thought this code would work and it so far has not.

Any suggestions about what is wrong?

Comment: I think to find the diagonals all you'd have to do is check when i == j right (because diagonal is at 0,0, 1,1, & 2,2). In terms of the rest of the logic I'm a little confused on what it is that your doing in your code. it seems your looping through but I think you need to compare with others in the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like homework, so I won't give a code solution. But you can tell when you're on a diagonal when either both indexes are equal (`i == j`), or when the indexes add up to one less than the dimension of the matrix (`i + j == SIZE - 1`.)

In the first case, you're on the first diagonal (top-left to bottom-right.) In the second case, you're on the second diagonal (top-right to bottom-left.)

This works for square matrices of any size.

Comment: Oh. I feel silly for missing that. I actually had it unrestricted before but removed it because the iterator would count the first coordinate as a match. Thanks for the tip.